# What is the origin of the "polarization catastophe"?

Tags: electromagnetism, solid-state-physics, dielectric

According to the Clausius-Mossotti relation,

$$
\frac{\epsilon_r - 1}{\epsilon_r + 2}=\frac{n\alpha}{3\epsilon_0}
$$

So when $n\alpha = 3\epsilon_0$, the relative permittivity $\epsilon_r$ approaches infinity. So clearly the CM relation fails at this limit, but what is the reason? Which erratic assumption that the CM relation is based on caused this "catastrophe"?

This is from *Solid State Physics* by Om Prakash Pahuja:

> In such condition the local electric field caused by the polarization increases faster than the elastic restoring forces on an ion in the crystal. This leads to an asymmetrical shift in ionic positions and hence the structure shows ferroelectricity.

But I'm not quite sure what that means. I don't think that the CM relationship relies on the classic model of electron motion:

$$
m\ddot{x}=-kx-eE_0e^{i\omega t}
$$

Comment: I am not sure that the relation actually "fails" as much as it points to a phase transition. The real problem with the derivation is that it doesn't take thermodynamic fluctuations into account. Just as in the case of ferromagnetism a valid theory of ferroelectricity needs to have a strong temperature dependence which is not the case for Clausius-Mossotti. I am not aware that a simple extension of this approach does exist (or that it could even exist) that could explain these phenomena any better than in the case of ferromagnets.

Comment: @CuriousOne Could you explain a bit more about how $\epsilon_r$ avoids really becoming $\infty$ at $n\alpha=3\epsilon_0$? The textbook explanation is that  $n\alpha$ can't be exactly $3\epsilon_0$ due to fluctuations, but is that really valid? Why won't $\epsilon_r$ still be averaged to $\infty$? Thank you!

Comment: It doesn't actually avoid that pole. It's really there, if you look at temperature dependent dielectric constants of ferroelectric substances near the transition temperature. The problem with the derivation of behavior around the critical point is that the correlation length of fluctuations becomes infinite, i.e. at some point the assumption that we can reduce the problem to a small sphere inside an otherwise homogenous material of infinite dimensions becomes unphysical as dielectric domains grow larger than the sphere and eventually large than an actual sample.